# Dispatching a variable in Mate Framework

Tags: apache-flex

I have a grid, when i click on the edit button it goes to edit page... but i need the value in the grid also to be passed to the page.

```
this.dispatchEvent(new DepManagementEvent(DepManagementEvent.EDIT_NAVI));
```

The above code lands in EDIT page... how can i move the values too.

My Parent Page code.

```
private function editForm():void {
                var event:DepManagementEvent = new DepManagementEvent("Edit Page",true);
                dispatchEvent(event);
            }
```

The Edit Page below....

```
public function init(event:DepManagementEvent):void {
        this.addEventListener(DepManagementEvent.EDIT_NAVI, onEditNavi);    
    }

    public function onEditNavi(event:DepManagementEvent):void {
        Alert.show("as");
    }
```

I am not getting the alert, when the page is navigated from the parent one.... on click. Also edit this code on how i can pass the variables too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a public var (called "navi" in the code below) to the DepManagementEvent that's of the same type as the item in the grid, then dispatch the event like this instead:

```
var event:DepManagementEvent = new DepManagementEvent( DepManagementEvent.EDIT_NAVI );
event.navi = grid.selectedItem;
dispatchEvent( event );
```

To listen to the event on the other side, you add an event listener for a function...

```
addEventListener( DepManagementEvent.EDIT_NAVI, onEditNavi);

private function onEditNavi( event:DepManagementEvent ):void
{
    // add logic here
}
```

Since you're in an itemRenderer, you can dispatch a bubbling event that will move up to the parent List/DataGrid and continue to bubble up to other parent views in the display hierarchy.  When you create the event, pass the second argument ("bubbles") as true:

```
new DepManagementEvent( DepManagementEvent.EDIT_NAVI, true );
```

Comment: How to listen the event at the other end, also the edit button of the grid is in different page as an itemRenderer.

Comment: `function eventHandler(event:DepManagementEvent){trace(event.navi);}`

Comment: listen to the button's click event in the class where item renderer is and dispatch this event from there.

Comment: I added a few examples above.

Comment: Thanks for the examples, i still dont get